# Is there a 'const pointer' in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

Have been working in Ruby for a while, but usually in the context of Rails.  I'm using it now for some deployment scripts, and I find myself looking for an immutable reference to an immutable value.

In C++, I'd have (I haven't touched C++ in years, so bear with me)

```
const int x = 5;
const int * const i = &x;
```

This would give me a variable i which would forever be pointing to 5.  I'm looking for a way to prevent redefining i.

In ruby, I have

```
i = 5.freeze
```

which covers the first const, but not the second.

```
i = 5
i = 6 # ideally generates an error or warning
```

This is mostly to help be program defensively.  Anything analogous?

(Yes, the root cause of this issue is that my script has grown too big and needs to be refactored in a major way.  It's on the backlog.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby's ["constants"](http://phrogz.net/ProgrammingRuby/) generate a warning when re-assigned. And, to ensure that the existing value isn't mutated, you can either freeze their value (as you did) or simply use an immutable value like a Symbol:

```
C:\>cat constant_reassignment.rb
FOO = :foo # Symbols are immutable, and a good choice for a sigil
FOO = :bar

C:\>ruby constant_reassignment.rb
constant_reassignment.rb:2: warning: already initialized constant FOO
```

If you need to programmatically define the values you can use [`const_set`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Module.html#method-i-const_set) on the Class/Module of your choice:

```
class Foo; end
p Foo.const_defined? "BAR"  #=> false
p Foo::BAR rescue nil # Would be NameError: uninitialized constant Foo::BAR

Foo.const_set "BAR", 42
p Foo::BAR #=> 42

Foo.const_set "BAR", 17
#=> warning: already initialized constant BAR
```

If you want a hard error raised, I suggest that you should create a method to define these for you and `raise` if `const_defined?` shows such a value already existing.

Comment: I'm using it for values generated/returned at runtime, though, not pre-known values.  This feels really unnatural.  This might be the only way.  It will just make my code look 'less good'.

Comment: @JohnHinnegan I've edited my answer to show how you can dynamically define a constant and get a warning if it was already defined.